# Spring Boot REST Controller Integration Test returns 406 instead of 500

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a controller with an endpoint that produces a byte stream of zipped data.  The `MyDtO` and `ZipService` classes in the code below are custom classes that function as a POJO whose contents I want to add to the zip and a service that will take the bytes of the POJO and write them to a `ZipOutputStream` which will then be made available via the endpoint wrapped in a `ResponseEntity` object with the appropriate `HttpStatus` and headers.  The “happy path” is working fine and is producing the zip file as expected.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}/export", produces = "application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> export(@ApiParam(required = true) @PathVariable(value = "id") String id) throws IOException {
    try {
        MyDTO myDTO = myService.getDTO(id);
        byte[] zippedData = zipService.createZip(myDTO.getBytes());
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""name.zip\"");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(zipDTO.getData(), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity(e.getRestError(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

The problem is in my integration test class when I want to test the case where a custom `ZipException` is thrown (which could happen if there is a problem with the data being zipped).  One of the standards we have to adhere to in our organization is that each custom exception needs to extend `Exception` and have a custom object called RestError that has String variables that represent custom error codes and messages.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class RestError {

    private String code;
    private String message;

    //Constructors

    //Getters and setters
}
```

This object seems to cause a problem with the integration tests

```
@Test
public void myIntegrationTest() throws Exception {
    MyDTO myDTO = new MyDTO();
    RestError restError = new RestError("Custom error code", "Custom error message")
    ZipException zipException = new ZipException(restError);
    given(myService.getDTO("id")).willReturn(myDTO);
    given(zipService.createZip(any(), any())).willThrow(zipException);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/{id}/export", "id").accept(MediaType.ALL)
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError());
}
```

I would expect a `HttpStatus` of 500 in that case but the `MockMvc` is hitting a `HttpStatus` of 406 - content unacceptable.  I’ve messed around with the test so that it can accept and expect any/all data but it still hits that 406 error every time.  I know it’s do do with the RestError object of the exception because if I take that out of the `ResponseEntity` that is returned by the controller then the expected response status is returned.  Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the produces from  `@GetMapping(path = "/{id}/export", produces = "application/zip")`
and change it to `@GetMapping(path = "/{id}/export")`

Due to this during test case execution 406 error is returned
You will get exact error what you are throwing if you remove this.

However check the zip file gets downloaded as expected or not.

Comment: Thank you, that worked and my endpoint is still downloading the zip correctly.  However why would the "produces" part of the annotation cause this issue?